# System doesn't boot on kernel 5.8.0-36

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I am running Kubuntu 20.04.

When I boot my system...

-first it goes to grub (I also have a windows install)
-then I select ubuntu
-then it goes back to the gigabyte mobo splash screen and stays there.

I then have to select Ubuntu advanced options in grub and select the kernel in the list 5.4.0-60. It then boots fine.

I assume the first kernel entry in the list 5.8.0-36 is the default one that is failing.

I am not sure if this is related, but this happened around the time I changed my video card. But at the same time I also updated my system and was behind on MANY packages. I assume the upgrade of packages is what precipitated the change. To be sure I swapped back in my old video card and the same boot issue persisted.

What is my best course of action moving forward to diagnose this issue?

Comment: Look in the `/boot` folder and make sure that there is a `config-5.8.0-36-generic`, `System.map-5.8.0-36-generic`, `initrd.img-5.8.0-36-generic` and `vmlinuz-5.8.0-36-generic`.  If any of those are missing run `sudo update-initramfs -u -k 5.8.0-36-generic` to help rebuild the boot files necessary.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS vanilla that just started today. I have a crash report in `/var/crash` that is related to `tracker-miner-fs`. Do you have the same?

Comment: I had a bunch of .crash files in there. I cleared them and then tried booting, and no new crash file appeared.

Comment: My issue turned out to be due to a very old NVIDIA graphics card that wasn't compatible with the newest set of drivers. See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1872950). I'll hold off on posting this as an answer in case your issue is different from mine.

Comment: I just removed my nvidia video card last week. Maybe I should purge all nvidia stuff off my system.

Comment: Could be that your issue is related, then. I posted an answer because even if for you it's not *the* answer, it may be *an* answer for anyone searching.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an older NVIDIA graphics card, this may be due to a driver incompatibility.

Per [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1872950),

> Installing the 340 driver will fail when running Linux 5.7 or newer.

The fact that 5.4.0-xx kernels boot to a window manager, but 5.8.0-xx kernels do not, suggests that this could be the problem.

See the bug report linked above for full details, but the following should fix the issue if an old NVIDIA card is the problem

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

This is what helped me:

`apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04`

My config is Kubuntu 20.04 and kernel 5.8.0-43-generic.

Comment: Had an identical issue as OP and this solution was the only one that worked.  Thanks!